# QThread run function with unknown number of arguments and types

Tags: c++, qt

I'm tyring to write a `QThread` function.
And in `run` function there is a function `m_pFunc` in the while loop.The `m_pFunc` is a function pointer with unknown number of arguments annd types.
How to achieve this function pointer?

```
void func1(int){ cout<<"func1"<<endl; }
void func2(int,char){ cout<<"func2"<<endl; }

class CThread: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(CThread)

public:
    using PFunc = void (*)(...); //how to achieve it?
    CThread() = default;
    ~CThread() = default;
    CThread(const PFunc pFunc) :
        m_bRunning(false),
        m_pFunc(pFunc){
    };

protected:
    void run()
    {
        m_bRunning = true;
        while (m_bRunning) {
            m_pFunc(...);       //how to run this function pointer?
        }
    }

private:
    std::atomic_bool m_bRunning;
    PFunc m_pFunc;
};

CThread ct1(func1);
CThread ct2(func2);
ct1.run();
ct1.run();
```

expected result：

> func1
> func2

Comment: How do you call a function with an unknown number of parameters? (What are you using as arguments for this call?) I believe your solution has to be a functor. To store the function, you could use e.g. `std::function<void()> m_pFunc;` which can be called with `m_pFunc();`. Now, you can assign plain functions as well as functors including capturing lambdas. Thus, the arguments for the function call can be passed in using a lambda as wrapper (or a function or a functor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CThread: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(CThread)

public:
    using PFunc = std::function<void()>; //use std::function
    CThread() = default;
    ~CThread() = default;

    template<class F>                    //template here
    CThread(F&& pFunc) :
        m_bRunning(false),
        m_pFunc(std::forward<F>(pFunc)){
    };

protected:
    void run()
    {
        m_bRunning = true;
        while (m_bRunning) {
            m_pFunc();           //call m_pFunc();
        }
    }

private:
    std::atomic_bool m_bRunning;
    PFunc m_pFunc;
};



CThread ct1(std::bind(func1,1));
CThread ct2(std::bind(func2,2,'a'));
ct1.run();
ct2.run();
```